# Threaded TCP connection - Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an Android app that will send some packets of data to an embedded device.
Since my embedded device is not supporting UDP datagram protocol, I would like to simulate it using sync TCP.

That being said, a response string from the device is not needed, so I would like to disconnect the TCP socket as soon as the data is sent from my app.

I would be grateful if someone could outline how to make a Thread that would perform the connection and close the socket if no data is received within some timeframe.

My current code is simple:

```
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",12345);

        //outgoing stream redirect to socket
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println("Hello Android!");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

        //read line(s)
        String st = input.readLine();
        . . .
        //Close connection
        s.close();


} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First take care about the protocol, if your application stuck at `String st = input.readLine();` so it doesn't mean server doesn't send data, because the `readLine()` method expect a line(end with CRLF), and this is possible that server just sends some string without line feed, then buffered reader still stucks the thread(current thread) because it expects the CRLF.
Next you would have another class which accepts the Socket as parameter, then waits for while, then close the socket because of no response from the server., something like this

```
class SocketMgr implements Runnable{
final private int timeout=5000;
private Socket s;
public SocketMgr(Socket s){this.s=s;new Thread(this).start();}
public void run(){
try{Thread.sleep(timeout);s.close();}catch(Exception ex){}
}
}
```

and in your code

```
 try {
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost",12345);

        //outgoing stream redirect to socket
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println("Hello Android!");
        output.flush();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        //////////////////////////////////
        new SocketMgr(s);
        //////////////////////////////////
        //read line(s)
        String st = input.readLine();
        . . .
        //Close connection
        s.close();


} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

also you would check this out for a simple [[java threading tutorial]](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html)
once again, this is important to know about the protocol belong to your server.
good luck, have a nice socket program :).

Comment: Thank you for your insights.
When I call new SocketMgr(s);
I get the following error:
Gradle: cannot find symbol constructor SocketMgr(java.net.Socket)
I'm relatively new to the OOP :(

Comment: Aw, sorry, typo mistake, I updated the code, please check again.

Comment: Thank you again.
This is probably a question for a new post.
I've defined internet permissions in manifest, but when i try to open a socket the app crashes. I have no idea why, the code for the TCP connection is simple and straightforward.

Comment: so make sure that server is listening at the related port and accept incoming connection, what kinda exception do you get?! would you share some code?!

Comment: I'm using the same code as above, with or without threading I get the same problem. The application just terminates on android: "the application has stopped". I don't even get UnknownHost exception before it crashes. I tried it on virtual and real device with the same results.

Comment: as I see your code, the client just gets the string from the server and after that method returns, maybe you need to show the received message. and make sure that server is reachable for the client.

Comment: Yes, I have no idea what is wrong, the server is reachable, and regardless of that the app just quit when i try to open the socket.
Maybe it's too much to ask, but could you please send me the the generic rudimental code to open a TCP connection to server and send some data that's proven to work (so I could eliminate other factors). This is very important for me because this is a part of my Masters thesis. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, first what does server do? would you share server code? this is really important about the data exchange between client and server, this helps me to provide you a better sample. or I would share a simple client/server sample.

Comment: Server is based on arduino open source platform. Code is basically a loop that checks if client is connected and then reads data.
WiFiClient client = sever.available();
if(client.connected()) {
charRead=client.read(); //reads the buffer
}

Comment: please check the updated code again, I just forgot to flush the data to the server. and about the error, add another catch block with Throwable class `catch(Throwable t){...}` and print the error inside it, maybe you get an unexpected error.

Comment: It seems I've resolved the problem. Thank you for helping the community! I wish I could buy you a beer or something :)

Comment: Cool, and what was the problem?